Numerical solution to 4 layer waveguide
Tried to solve this equation for a week with multiple initial guesses using Muller method ( In scilab ) . But no success as of now. Tested the algorithm by finding root for various different complex equation, but not able to solve below equation.
$$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{K_1}{iK_2}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left[ \frac{K_3}{K_2} \tan\left( \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{K_4}{iK_3} \right) \right) - U_3 t_3  \right] - U_2t_2 = 0   $$
$$ \text{Where  }K_n = U_n = \frac{2\pi} {\lambda_o} \sqrt{n_n^2 - n_w^2} $$
Paper: https://opg.optica.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-64-3-274
clear;clc;

n1 = 1.53             // Substrate material (glass)
n2 = 1.55             // Guiding layer material (glass)
n3 = 1.32             // Isolation layer material (sodium fluoride, NaF)
n4 = 0.162 + 3.43*%i  // Metal layer material (gold) ( Complex R.I.)

t2 = 1.4              // Guiding layer thickness 
lambda = 0.6328       // Operating wavelength
m = 0                 // Fundamental mode

x = [1.53, 1.54, 1.55] // Initial Guess 

t3 = 0.05

function y = f(x)     // Equation to be solved
    term1 = atan(sqrt(n1^2-x^2)/(%i*sqrt(n2^2-x^2)))
    subterm = atan(sqrt(n4^2-x^2)/(%i*sqrt(n3^2-x^2)))-(2*%pi/lambda)*sqrt(n3^2-x^2)*t3
    term2 = atan(sqrt((n3^2-x^2)/(n2^2-x^2))*tan(subterm))
    term3 = (2*%pi/lambda)*t2*sqrt((n2^2-x^2))
    y = term1+term2-term3-m*%pi
endfunction

// Muller algorithm start 

function x_n = X(x)    // Function to find next value of x 
    den = (x(2)-x(3))*(x(1)-x(2))*(x(1)-x(3))
    a = [(x(2)-x(3))*f(x(1))-(x(1)-x(3))*f(x(2))+(x(1)-x(2))*f(x(3))]/den
    b = -[(x(2)^2-x(3)^2)*f(x(1))-(x(1)^2-x(3)^2)*f(x(2))+(x(1)^2-x(2)^2)*f(x(3))]/den
    c =  [x(2)*x(3)*(x(2)-x(3))*f(x(1))-x(1)*x(3)*(x(1)-x(3))*f(x(2))+x(1)*x(2)*(x(1)-x(2))*f(x(3))]/den

    root = [[-b + sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)]/(2*a),[-b - sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)]/(2*a)]
    if (abs(f(root(1))) < abs(f(root(2))))
        x_n = root(1)
    else
        x_n = root(2)
    end
endfunction

tol = 1e-10  // tolerance 

function [y] = root_Muller(x)   // Muller method iteration 
    X3 = X(x)
    i = 0                       // Iteration 
    while (abs(f(X3)) > tol )
        i = i + 1 
        dist = [ abs(x(1) -X3),  abs(x(2) -X3),  abs(x(3) -X3) ]
        x(find(dist == max(dist))) = X3
        X3 = X(x)
        disp(X3)
    end
    y = X3
endfunction

// Muller algorithm end
 
root = root_Muller(x)

disp(root, f(root))


Welcome to SciComp.SE. What is that you want to solve? I'm guessing that you are obtaining a characteristic equation and you want to find the roots of that,  a trascendental equation. What is the variable that you are solving for?

Trying to solve given equation for $ n_w $ where  $ n_1, n_2, n_3 $
and  $ n_4 $  are known.

Any particular reason why you are using Muller's method, which is a quite niche method in my experience? Are you looking for the best way to solve that equation, or are you trying to test your implementation of Muller's method on a difficult problem?

@FedericoPoloni   I tried other methods too like Newton-Raphson method ( which didn't work ) , but this method is specifically used by article author ( added to the post ) to get complex roots .  Also looking for best way to solve the equation, if any. In equation $ n_4 $ is complex.

A good way to start with solving a nonlinear equation is always to plot the function. This gives you an idea of how smooth/nonsmooth/unique/non-unique the function and its roots are going to be. Have you plotted the function? If so, could you add such a plot?

In general, I suggest using a numerical method for eigenvalues in the continuous differential equation directly instead of trying to solve the characteristic equations. This applies to polynomial equations and transcendental equations as well. Methods such as the Ritz, Finite Difference, or Finite Element can be used.
If you insist on finding your equation's roots, I would suggest some kind of manipulation (see this answer). In your case, I suspect that in the original form maybe it was written in terms of sines and cosines instead of tangents (and inverse tangents). For example, $ \sin(x) - \cos(x) = 0$ and $ \tan(x) - 1 = 0$ might look the same but the first function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and the second is not. This is important to the convergence of the method.
